# R - xgb.importance after xgb.cv

Tags: r, cross-validation, xgboost

I used to look at the importance of the variables after building an xgboost model with `xgb.train()` in R. Here is an example with the dataset `mtcars`.

```
library(xgboost)
library(tidyverse)

xgb_mtcars <- xgb.DMatrix(
  data    = mtcars[,-1] %>% as.matrix(),
  label   = mtcars$mpg
)

xgb_Param <- list(
  booster          = 'gbtree',
  tree_method      = 'hist',
  eta              = .3
)

xgb_mod_1 <- xgb.train(
  data      = xgb_mtcars,
  params    = xgb_Param,
  nround    = 50
)

xgb.importance(dimnames(xgb_mtcars)[[2]], model = xgb_mod_1) %>% head()
#    Feature       Gain      Cover  Frequency
# 1:     cyl 0.43871401 0.01712283 0.03266788
# 2:      wt 0.30334298 0.11487124 0.13611615
# 3:    disp 0.18704847 0.40043144 0.34482759
# 4:      hp 0.04358683 0.11298369 0.12522686
# 5:    qsec 0.01397431 0.19091277 0.20689655
# 6:    drat 0.01082511 0.08520965 0.10344828
```

Today, I'm trying to use `xgb.cv()`, in order to make k-folds with the dataset and prevent overfitting. But the function `xgb.importance()` doesn't work any more.
In the help of this function, it said that the model need to come from xgb.train().

```
xgb_mod_2 <- xgb.cv(
  data      = xgb_mtcars,
  params    = xgb_Param,
  nfold     = 3,
  nround    = 50
)

xgb.importance(dimnames(xgb_mtcars)[[2]], model = xgb_mod_2) %>% head()
# Error in xgb.importance(dimnames(xgb_mtcars)[[2]], model = xgb_mod_2) : 
#   model: must be an object of class xgb.Booster
```

**Questions** : is there a way to calculate variables importance after `xgb.cv()` ? Or maybe to have this importance only for one fold.

I didn't find anything in the internet. Does it mean `xgb.cv()` is only used to tune parameters, and then, when the "best" parameters are fixed, an `xgb.train()` need to be run again ?

Comment: My understanding is that `xgb.cv` is more for cross-validation (i.e., testing stability) than for feature importance (which is the case for a single xgb), thus the model performance score in `evaluation_log` is more interesting than individual feature importance. I certainly agree that something like average feature importance can be added, but if you really want it, you can do your 3-fold cv manually and extract the feature importance from each individual xgb classifier. It's just a matter of splitting your data into 3 partitions.

Comment: thank you for you comment. Indeed, I made the cross validation manually, but I always find it uneffective when it exists a function that is programmed for doing it.

Comment: If I were you and if I will probably use it in the future as well, I will write a function for it and save it somewhere that I can grab and call efficiently.